# GTK(MM) Widget Choice for List of Items

Tags: gui, gtk, widgets

I am working on an interface with GTKMM and I have a notebook with buttons that represent certain letters. When I click a button it switches to page two of the notebook which will have a selection of all choices starting with the letter of the button that was clicked.

I have done everything except the list of choices. This is where my issue is: I couldn't find any documentation on a `gtk listbox` even though this is a very simple widget that I have seen in multiple GUI libraries.

I don't want to use tree-view unless I have to because that is very complicated and overkill for my needs. All I need is:

- Widget that lists user selectable options
- Ability to select more than one item
  I also don't want a combo box for the reasons above and because this will be used on a 3.5" resistive touchscreen so the buttons need to be big.

Any ideas?